# Switch microphone to speakerphone mic

Tags: nexus-5, microphone

My primary mic seems to be broken. Google Now voice search records no audio and while in call the other side can not hear me talk. [Booting to safe mode](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2852139) does not help either.

However when I switch to speakerphone, all is working well. As far as I've read the Nexus 5 uses another mic in speaker phone mode (noise cancellation).

Is it somehow possible to always use the speakerphone mic? Since it is the only one working for me.

Comment: yes, it is rooted

Answer (score 1):

I found two apps 
one free - Auto speaker [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.swarly.autospeaker&hl=en)
Try the free one first

second Tasker - Paid [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)

It has lots of automating features beside your need.
Before paying for App Read the tutorial first.
To use tasker use this tutorial [link](http://android.wonderhowto.com/how-to/automatically-turn-speakerphone-when-you-arent-holding-your-android-device-your-ear-0159325/)

Both apps uses sensors. Try on you device.

Comment: Both apps seam to be able to trigger speakerphone mode. But that's not what I'm looking for. I could switch to speakerphone mode myself using the in-call button. But that would switch the speaker as well as the microphone. I'm looking to switch the microphone only. I think there is no native Android call to change that behavior, since most devices do not have different microphones. I guess its part of the nexus 5 firmware.

Comment: I do not recall or found any such application to switch mic permanently without switching speakerphone. With dual microphone, you can get custom build application for your need for your device. But I rather suggest you to get that mic replaced with authorized service center.